# Linq to Entities NOT throwing Null reference exception for Left Join

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities, left-join

**In Linq to Object:**
While accessing right table object of left outer join result set , the query will throw Null reference Exception.

```cs
    var customers = new Customer[]
    {
        new Customer{Code = 5, Name = "Sam"},
        new Customer{Code = 6, Name = "Dave"},
        new Customer{Code = 7, Name = "Julia"},
        new Customer{Code = 8, Name = "Sue"}
    };


    var orders = new Order[]
    {
        new Order{KeyCode = 5, Product = "Book"},
        //new Order{KeyCode = 6, Product = "Game"},
        new Order{KeyCode = 7, Product = "Computer"},
        new Order{KeyCode = 7, Product = "Mouse"},
        new Order{KeyCode = 8, Product = "Shirt"},
        new Order{KeyCode = 5, Product = "Underwear"}
    };

    var query = customers.GroupJoin(orders,
        c => c.Code,
        o => o.KeyCode,
        (customer, order) => new { customer,order})
        .SelectMany(q => q.order.DefaultIfEmpty(),(q,order)=>new{q.customer,order});

    query.Where(l => l.order.Product.Contains("Book")).Dump();
```

Assume Customer and Order Data mentioned above as in SQLServer. The Same Query (i.e. now as **LINQ to EF** ) is not throwing null reference exception. It just returns the record.

> Why it is not throwing null reference exception ? Even `Order` object
>   for `Customer`{Code:6, Name:"Dave"} is null

**Edit:**
I tried with little variations as follows.

```cs
var result = query.Where(l => l.order.Product.Contains("Book")).ToList();
```

Above query not throwing Null Reference Exception

```cs
var result = query.ToList().Where(l => l.order.Product.Contains("Book"));
```

This query throwing Exception

Both queries on table with nearly 50,000 records not throwing exception.

In my Production environment Similar query but the magnitude of 50,000 records rather than 4 or 6 records. In Data Access Layer I am returning the query result as `List` after applying all `Where` filter. There was no exception thrown and system is working fine.

> Do I need to Check null on `Order` object in `Where` Predicate as in
>   Alex Zaitsev's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46112581/449413) ?

Comment: Does the answer helps?

Answer (score 1):

This is because of lazy execution behaviour of Linq. Actually it is null but it will be visible only when you are trying to convert to list, that time only query will execute. Please try to convert to List like below,

```
var result =  query.Where(l => l.order.Product.Contains("Book")).ToList();
```

You will get a "NullReferenceException"